# if $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly convergent then for all functions $h$ the sequence $\{f_n+h\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is also uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

For any functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, 
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if
$\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly convergent then for every function 
$h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ 
the sequence 
$\{f_n+h\}_{n=1}^\infty$ 
is also uniformly convergent.

I think this would be true, as if $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$, then $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) + g(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and $|f_n(x) + g(x) - f(x) - g(x)| = |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: That's pretty much it (using $h$ instead of $g$, I guess). You should spell out the uniform convergence specifically rather than just pointwise convergence, but it still works out.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ then for any function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)+h(x) - (f(x)+h(x))| = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0,
$$
so that $f_n+h$ converges uniformly to $f+h$.